# password does not work with useradd -p

Tags: password, adduser, useradd

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I ran the following command to create a user

```
$sudo useradd -m -p password1 guest_user
```

and then tried to switch to the user with

```
$su guest_user
```

But i could not login with password1

Am i missing something? Am i suppose to login with password1 or something else as  -p option says in the man page for useradd

```
 -p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

           Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be
           visible by users listing the processes.

           You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
```

The above confuses me because when i type the command

useradd -m -p password1

the password password1 is visible on the command line. How to make it invisible in the above command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `man useradd` :

```
-p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
```

As you can see the `PASSWORD` with `-p` option is the encrypted password returned by the `crypt(3)` library function.

If you use `-p password1`, the system will consider this plain text `password1` as the encrypted shadow password entry in `/etc/shadow`.

The solution is to use the encrypted password here with `-p` which is **unsafe**, you should set the password interactively.

For example create the user first :

```
sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash guest_user
```

Now set the password :

```
sudo passwd guest_user
```

Or better use `adduser` instead :

```
sudo adduser --gecos '' guest_user
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `perl` to print the encrypted password and use it with `-p` option in `useradd` command.

```
$ sudo useradd -m -p $(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' 'YOUR_PASSWORD') username
```

You also can use it with other options like `-s` for Shell or `-d` for home directory.

Comment: The second option to `crypt` is salt and is fixed to `password` on all linuxes? If this is false, one can use `chpasswd` utility.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an argument after each option you want to use. For example:

```
    useradd -m guest_user -p passwd1
```

As the useradd man page suggests, adding your password in this way is not considered secure because it is transmitted in plain text. For an alternative, try:

```
    sudo useradd -m guest_user
```

and then:

```
    sudo passwd guest_user
```

Two caveats:

- the line that begins with: NAME_REGEX= in: /etc/adduser.conf may prohibit the use of the underscore "_" character for usernames;
- there may be password complexity requirements set in: /etc/pam.d/common-password which require a more complex password.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to doing what you want is:

```bsh
$ sudo su
# useradd -m USER && echo "USER:PASSWORD" | chpasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
myAddUser() {
      # check for this in '/etc/passwd' and '/etc/shadow'
      # $1 is the username
      # $2 is the password
      sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m -p $(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' "$2") "$1" 
  }
```

Like this:

```
  myAddUser mostafa 1557 "This is the only user"
```

You can also source the function and use it as you wish!

> This is a modification of [Chhaileng](https://askubuntu.com/users/1013188/chhaileng) answer.